# Should it be will or would after present perfect?

Tags: grammar, tense

My experiences have told me that my interest would/will never decrease.
Which one is better and what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experiences have told me that my interest will\ would never decrese.

Here **will** talks about certainity in future better than **would**. so  **will** should  be used.It is nothing to do with the present perfect.But if it is a past tense would is the only option.

Here is a link which helps you.

https://www.grammar.com/when_to_use_%E2%80%9Cwould%E2%80%9D_instead_of_%E2%80%9Cwill%E2%80%9D

Comment: That really helps. Thank you!